# Convert String to Currency inside formula

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a field that some times is a string and some times is a number, the number must be displayed as currency.

If I just drag the field from the field explorer, I can easily change the number displayed as currency, I tried to do that inside the formula using this one:

```
CCur ({infCarga.vCarga})
```

Input (from XML):     `180420.00`

Result:              `$18.042.000,0000`

I need this:    `R$ 180.420,00 (Brazillian currency)`

Comment: Do you need the '(Brazillian currency)' bit or is that just informational for us?

Comment: No, it's just information about the "R$";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula field to convert a string to a numeric:

```
// {@BRL}
ToNumber({infCarga.vCarga})
```

Add the formula field to the canvas, right click it and select 'Format Field...'.

Select the Number tab and click Customize...

Change the 'Decimal Separator' to ',' and Thousands Separator to '.':

[image]

Next add the desired currency symbol:

[image]

If you need the additional text, add a Text Object, insert the desired text, then drag the formula field to the text object:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the ToNumber, so the section "Numbers" was hidden. :D